# How do I get the currently logged address in front end template?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-front-end

What I´m trying to do is to condition some `option/modal` to be shown in the screen depending on the logged `user/account` being the owner or not so to have something similar to:

```
accountPair.address === NFT.owner
```

I know it has to be related with the addresses inside `keyring`. But how do I identify the current account being logged in the UI? I´m working with the `front end template` of polkadot js.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hook `useSubstrateState` (see the code [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/main/src/substrate-lib/SubstrateContext.js)).
An example is:

```js
const { api, currentAccount } = useSubstrateState()
const yourAddress = currentAccount.address;
```